# When I try to start my Visual Studio, it says "The requested operation operation requires elevation."

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Had just registered my subscription key on the VS Pro Demo Version. After successful registration, I restarted the computer. Now, When I try to restart Visual Studio, it gives a following error message.
[image]

I have tried to run as administrator. The admin and password works for cmd.exe but not for the visualstudio.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I still do not know **WHY** of the problem. Still, this is how I was able to start Visual Studio Pro.

Right clicked on the VS logo **>>** Troubleshoot compatibility **>>** Start the program

click 'Next' to save the setting.

PS: *I have tried the same admin username and password this time, and it worked.*

Answer (score 0):

Right clicked on the VS logo >> Run as administrator and change the setting in the properties of the built exe to Run the exe as administrator